# How to check if a particular dictionary exists in a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to know if a dictionary named 'behavior' with a key named apistats exists in my json file that i am opening so that if it exists I can do further processing, and if it doesnt exist so the next file opens

I have tried putting condition if dictionary with apistats exist or not , but it gives error.
Also I can't put a check on only the key apistats in behavior, because for some files behavior dictionary doesnt exist at all

```
    for filename in glob.glob('*.json'):
             with open(filename) as json_file:
                      data=json.load(json_file)
                      if data['behavior']['apistats']:
                              print ('exists')
                      else:
                      print("doesn't")


    Expected:
    exists
    exists
    doesn't
    Actual Output: 
    File "C:/Users/sidra/Desktop/extractor/ectractor.py", line 12, in <module>
    if data['behavior']['apistats']:

    KeyError: 'apistats'
```

Comment: `if 'behavior' in data and 'apistats' in data['behavior']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for a key in a dictionary as:

```py
if key in dictionary:
   ...
```

For example:

```
if "behavior" in data:
    if "apistats" in data["behavior"]:
        ...
```

Or just put your control in a try - except block:

```
try:
    if some control that throws exception: 
       ... 

except: 
    print("does not exist")
    pass
```